# Can I reuse Dialog Interface's single onclicklistener for two difference Alert Dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have two Dialogs which performs difference activities.

My query is can I use a single onclicklistener to do different function?

for example:

```
private OnClickListener onOkClickListener = new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
                   if ( first dialog's ok button clicked)
                   {    
                        /*  some actions*/
                   }
                   else if ( second dialog's ok button clicked)
                   {
                        /*  some other actions*/
                   }

            }
    };
```

Some one please help me to do this stuff..

Comment: You can if you let your Activity implement the DialogInterface.OnClickListener (not completely sure about the name). And then for every Dialog use setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: Yes you can better if you will look to use interface concept. You need to create object of your interface(by anonymous class) that same object you can pass or you can implement it in your class directly in which you are using dialog and pass class_name.this

Comment: I love to use single onClicklistener for two different Alert dialogs ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single listener for two or more button is possible for these dialog and fragments and all...

I have figured it by some tutorials.  and here is the answer.

By setting tagName to those particular dialogs or fragments we can differentiate the context and can reuse the same listeners.
Example code:

```
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), fragment1_tag);

dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), fragment2_tag);
```

And below is the only one listener that will be reused by tag name.

```
View.onClickListener okButtonListener(new View.onClickListener{
   public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
   {
     if( view.getTag().equals("fragment1_tag") )
     {
        //Do operation
     }
     else if( view.getTag().equals("fragment2_tag") )
     {
        //Do operations
     }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes. you can use. consider this example...

```
    final DialogInterface.OnClickListener clickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
            String s = (String) alertDialog.getButton(
                    DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).getTag();
            boolean isDialog1 = s.equals("DIALOG1");
            switch (which) {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                if(isDialog1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Negative in Dialog1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Negative in Dialog2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL:
                if(isDialog1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Neutral in Dialog1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Neutral in Dialog2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                if(isDialog1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Positive in Dialog1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Positive in Dialog2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    };

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    SecondActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Dialog1 Title");
            builder.setMessage("Dialog1 Message");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", clickListener);
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", clickListener);
            builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", clickListener);
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTag(
                    "DIALOG1");
        }
    });

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    SecondActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Dialog2 Title");
            builder.setMessage("Dialog2 Message");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", clickListener);
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", clickListener);
            builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", clickListener);
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTag(
                    "DIALOG2");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry @gopal-rao, This is not what i meant.    I love to use single onClicklistener for two different Alert dialogs ...